# I am trying to run the following SQL code with EXISTS keyword, could you help me with where I might be going wrong

Tags: mysql, sql, exists

```sql
select p.ProductID,
       p.ProductName,
       p.CategoryID
from   Products as p
where  p.CategoryID EXISTS (
         select *
         from   Categories as c
         where  c.CategoryID = p.CategoryID
       ) ;
```

ERROR: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXISTS'.

Comment: `where p.CategoryID EXISTS (SELECT ...)` should be just `where EXISTS (SELECT ...)`. Apart from that, the query should work. Voting for typo closure.

Answer (score 0):

There is no column name before `exists`:

```
select p.ProductID, p.ProductName, p.CategoryID
from Products p
where exist (select 1
              from Categories c
              where c.CategoryID = p.CategoryID
             ) ;
```

I prefer `select 1` for the subquery because it is easy to type.  Nothing is wrong, though, with `select *`.